# Error installing and running GridDB on Linux

Tags: linux, griddb

I am trying to install and run GridDB on a Linux system, but I am encountering an error during the installation process.

```
$ wget https://download.toshiba.com/developer/files/griddb/griddb_ce-4.6.0-1.linux.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh griddb_ce-4.6.0-1.linux.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo gs_startnode -u admin/admin
gs_startnode: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```